# Thermal Stream messed up when calling a C program to run using a Python program

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dlib

Using a Lepton 3 series thermal sensor, raspberrypi 4, and a generic RGB camera - I have a C program to run the Thermal camera and it runs a video feed just fine on its own.

However, I need to run everything in Python for this project, so I made a Python program to call the C program to run the Thermal camera.

The code to call thermal cam feed (in C) from python:

```
    import os 
    import subprocess 
    import dlib_adafruit_picture as camVideo
    filePath = r"/home/pi/LeptonModule-master/software/raspberrypi_video"       
    subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(filePath, "raspberrypi_video"),       shell=True)
    camVideo.main()
    input()
```

[Messed up thermal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVTbT.jpg)

[Good thermal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD4Lk.jpg)